# How to make Oracle DB SQL print out two columns side by side with no correlation?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I currently have two queries that output different numbers of names and I want to list them side by side. Say:

```
 select *
 from group A;
 where.....................;


 select *
 from group B;
 where ..................;
```

A gives me: John, Ana, Joseph while B gives me Bob, Juan, Nick, Jess

Then if I do:

```
 select name1, name2 
 from
 (select name1
 from group A;
 where.....................),
 (select name2
 from group B;
 where ..................)
 ;
```

I want to get

```
    name1    name2
  -----------------
  | John   |  Bob |
  | Ana    |  Juan|
  |Joseph  | Nick |
  |        | Jess |
```

but so far my outputs are grouped by first column name, so for each name in name1, there are 4 names corresponding in name2, like such:

```
    name1    name2
  ---------------------
  | John   |  Bob |
  | John   |  Juan|
  | John   | Nick |
  | John   | Jess |
  |  Ana   |  Bob |
  |  Ana   |  Juan|
  |  Ana   | Nick |
  |  Ana   | Jess |
  ...
```

Anyway I can get my desired output I mentioned above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a full outer join ("outer" to allow for lists of different length, and "full" since you don't know which one is longer). In a slightly more complicated query, you can also order your two lists (for example alphabetically, or by any other criteria you may have in your data).

For example:

```
with A (name1) as (select 'John'   from dual union all 
                   select 'Ana'    from dual union all
                   select 'Joseph' from dual),
     B (name2) as (select 'Bob'    from dual union all
                   select 'Juan'   from dual union all
                   select 'Nick'   from dual union all
                   select 'Jess'   from dual)
select name1, name2
from (select name1, row_number() over (order by name1) rn from A) aaa
full outer join
     (select name2, row_number() over (order by name2) rn from B) bbb
on aaa.rn = bbb.rn;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME1  NAME2
------ -----
Ana    Bob
John   Jess
Joseph Juan
       Nick
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a row number to each row in each subquery and use that as a pseudo-join-condition:

```
with a as (
  select name1, row_number() over (order by ...) as rn
  from group_a
  where ...
),
b as (
  select name2, row_number() over (order by ...) as rn
  from group_b
  where ...
)
select a.name1, b.name2 
from a
full outer join b on b.rn = a.rn;
```

I've used subquery factoring (CTEs, or 'with' clauses) to make it easier to use (or follow, anyway) a full outer join between the two result sets, but that isn't necessary - you can use inline views if you prefer; and I've done a full outer join because you expect the two subqueries to have different numbers of rows, but you may not know which subquery will return *more* rows.

You aren't currently ordering the results in either subquery, so the values are in an arbitrary and indeterminate order. If you did want them ordered you'd do that inside the `row_number() over (order by ...)` part, replacing the `...` with the ordering criteria - e.g. `(order by name1)` If you really don't want them ordered in a specific way you can order by a constant, or null, or a random value.